# Join two tables in mysql and read values from the second table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the names by matching the value of att_card_no in the `ent` table to cardno in the att_user table.

```
try {
    $att = $att->query('select att_time,att_date,att_card_no from att_detail WHERE att_card_no IN (select name from att_user where cardno="2342323423")');
    $att -> execute();
    $result = $att -> fetch();
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $att . "<BR>" . $e->getMessage();
}

    $att -> execute();
?>


    <?php echo "Name: ".$result['att_card_no']; ?>



Table:att_detail
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
| no      | att_time | att_date    | att_card_no|
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|       1 | 08:01    | 11-12-17    | 2342323423 |
|       2 | 08:02    | 12-12-17    | 4574574577 |
|       3 | 08:03    | 13-12-17    | 4656456796 |
|       4 | 08:04    | 14-12-17    | 9343450984 |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+

Table: att_user
+----+-------------+-------------+
| no |    name     |    cardno   |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | name1       |  2342323423 |
|  2 | name2       |  4574574577 |
|  3 | name3       |  4656456796 |
|  4 | name4       |  9343450984 |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

But the name value from att_user is not displayed.  Appreciate in understanding what is wrong here.  There are no errors throwing up too.

Edit: If you cannot answer it or if you find a similar Q that solves my problem please let me know because my searches did not find any but down voting this question is not helping a bit

Comment: Why should "name" be displayed if you didn't select it? And why do you think that "att_card_no" is in "select name..."?

Comment: @MichaelO.If you scroll across you can see that I did select it and its in the second table att_user.  Check the tables

Comment: `WHERE att_card_no IN (select name` does not make sense because `att_card_no` is a column with numbers, and `name` is a column with strings.

Comment: @MichaelO. Sorry but is my query confusing?  Why does it not make sense/

Comment: See Sloan Thrasher's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` query like below:-

```
(SELECT att_user.name,att_detail.att_time,att_detail.att_date,att_detail.att_card_no FROM att_user LEFT JOIN att_detail on  att_user.cardno = att_detail.att_card_no WHERE att_user.cardno="2342323423");
```

***Note:-***

You query is actually converted like this:-

```
'select att_time,att_date,att_card_no from att_detail WHERE att_card_no IN ("name1")'
```

So basically no `name` column is selected there, and hens it not coming.

Comment: It worked....
Can you tell me what was wrong with my sql statement that it did not work?

Comment: @X10nD i ave added explanation why your code not worked in Note section,have a look.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your SQL statement.

Since name isn't in the select's list of columns, it won't be in the result 
set. In your where, you are trying to match on att_card_no = name which won't
ever match.

Here's your SQL statement:

```
select 
    att_time,
    att_date,
    att_card_no 
from att_detail 
WHERE att_card_no IN (select name from att_user where cardno="2342323423")
```

But this is what you really want:

```
select 
    b.`name`,
    a.`att_time`,
    a.`att_date`,
    a.`att_card_no` 
from ent a 
JOIN att_user b
ON a.`att_card_no` = b.`cardno`;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a JOIN

```
 $att = $att->query('
    select a.att_time
    , a.att_date
    , a.att_card_no 
    , b.name 
  from att_detail  as a
  inner join att_user as b on a.att_card_no = b.card_no and b.cardno="2342323423"'
```